# Difference between input[type=hidden] and visibility="hidden"

Tags: html, css

What's the difference between `input[type=hidden]` and `visibility : hidden;` ?

Comment: One is an input element, the other is a style.

Comment: I think he really meant to ask about `<input type="hidden">` versus `<input type="text" style="visibility: hidden">`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first one is input element and the second is used for style in CSS2.

`visibility: hidden;` The visibility property specifies whether or not an element is visible.

**[input[type=hidden]](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/html/tagpages/i/inputhidden.htm)** :- HIDDEN is a TYPE attribute value to the INPUT element for FORMs. It indicates a form field that does not appear visibly in the document and that the user does not interact with. It can be used to transmit state information about the client or server.

Answer (score 3):

I’m assuming you mean what is the difference between `<input type="hidden" />` and  with CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

If that’s the case then the first one is a DOM type but still in the structure, the second is a style method to remove the item from the DOM structure.

Comment: `display: none` doesn't remove the item from the DOM, it just keeps it from being rendered.

Comment: `display:none` is not `visibility: hidden`, see: [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 2):

`input[type=hidden]` is definitely a selector, which matches every `input` element which has `type` attribute value set to `hidden`.

I have no idea what `visibility="hidden"` is. It **could** be CSS property, but incorrect one. It should be `visibility: hidden;` to be valid.

Comment: @Omega That's interesting. Any link to source about that usage?

Comment: Hmm, it's exactly what I've wrote about: it has to be `visibility: hidden` to be valid CSS. His text uses `"`s and `=`, and is not correct CSS.

Answer (score 2):

```
input[type=hidden]
```

This is a DOM selector (jQuery, CSS, etc.) for any `input` elements where the `type` attribute is `"hidden"`.  It doesn't have anything to do with actually displaying or hiding those elements, aside from the fact that browsers don't render `<input type="hidden" />` elements.

```
visibility="hidden"
```

This is setting the [CSS `visibility` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) to the value "hidden" which would tell the browser to not render whatever element(s) to which you're applying that attribute.  This is entirely about display of HTML elements and doesn't have anything to do with selectors or form elements as the other example does.

Comment: ahem... "CSS visibility attribute", really?

Comment: @Christophe: "Property" then?  It's clearly being set using JavaScript in some way, possibly incorrectly.  But it's a CSS property nonetheless.