# Difference between type="hidden" and hidden as an attribute

Tags: html

I noticed two patterns in my web app used in forms, and I can't remember how they got there.

One passes tokens around with `<input ... type="hidden" />`, and other parts use `<input ... hidden />`.

I looked at the MDN page for the [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) and the [type=](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden), and they seem exactly the same.

I went to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107040/whats-the-difference-between-html-hidden-and-aria-hidden-attributes), and it seemed to indicate that the `hidden` attribute would hide the display, but not from other user-output methods (like screen readers).  But it doesn't say anything about using `type="hidden"`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674912/difference-between-inputtype-hidden-and-visibility-hidden) talks about display and the `type="hidden"`, but doesn't mention other types of user-output methods.

How are these two handled differently by different output devices?  How are they handled differently by forms?  Are they treated differently by the DOM or DOM-stuff?

Is there some functional difference between these two?  Is there some "best practices" difference?  Some "expected way to do this" difference?

Comment: The `hidden` attribute is presentational, and similar to `display:none`, whereas the `<input type="hidden">`, while not visible, is meant to convey form data. The `hidden` attribute can be manipulated via CSS and JavaScript and can aid screen readers.

Comment: https://caniuse.com/?search=hidden

Answer (score 6):

When you have markup such as `<input hidden>` it's actually a shortcut for `<input hidden="hidden">` which is obviously different from `<input type="hidden">`.

The [documentation of `hidden` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) describes it as basically same as attribute `style="display:none"` without explicitly saying so to allow theoretical user agents (UA) that support attribute `hidden` but do not support CSS. At least in theory attribute `hidden` could also work when `Content-Security-Policy` prevents `style` attribute from working but this detail is not defined anywhere as far as I know.

Elements hidden with attribute `hidden="hidden"` can still be submitted because the above documentation explicitly says

> Hidden elements shouldn't be linked from non-hidden elements, and
> elements that are descendants of a hidden element are still active,
> which means that script elements can still execute and **form elements
> can still submit**. Elements and scripts may, however, refer to elements
> that are hidden in other contexts.

Real world user agents (e.g. Firefox and Chrome) may not send the inputs with  effective CSS style `display:none` but that's not actually the behavior described by the documentation.

The [documentation of input `type` attribute value `hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) explicitly says that inputs with this attribute will be submitted for that form element but cannot be modified or viewed by the user. (However, this cannot be used to avoid doing server-side security checks because user can still use e.g. developer tools to inspect or modify the value.)

**TL;DR:** You should use `type="hidden"` if you want to submit a hidden form element and `hidden="hidden"` or CSS styles if you just want to hide the element from the visitor. The difference is more semantic than practical but `type="hidden"` is better supported by really old user agents.

Comment: `type="hidden"` does NOT disable the submission of a form element. The very documentation you linked states that it lets you "include data that cannot be seen or modified by users when a form is submitted".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I don't know what I was thinking when I wrote the erroneous claims – I've been writing web applications for 20 years as my daily job so I should know well enough how `type=hidden` works in real world but  somehow I still wrote total nonsense. I fixed the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Also in some browsers, using the attribute "hidden" limits the input content in the attribute "value", p.e, in the case of chrome for iOS this limit is set to 500ko.
Another difference is that the attribute "hidden" [is not 100% supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=hidden) as if today.